# Firefox displaying <DIV> incorrectly - HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, firefox

I wasn't too sure how to word the title as its a rather obscure issue.

Essentially if you go to http://www.discovertheplanet.net click on one of the 3 boxes and if you are on firefox you will see the issue. If you view on IE or Chrome the menu on the left hand side is in the correct position, however on Firefox it starts way down the page.

I have viewed the console and there were a few CSS errors referring to the bootstrap.css. I have been on the Bootstrap website for known issues with firefox but there was nothing relevant.

**My HTML for the main are where the menu is:**

```
<!-- Main Body Area -->

<div class="main-container-notes">
    <div id="left-box">
        <?php 

        echo "<div style='width: 100%; display: table;'>";

        while( $noteName = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $resultNotes, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) 
        {
            echo "<div class='hvr-bounce-to-right1 hover-cursor' style='width: 100%; border-right: 5px solid #00AA88; height: 50px;'>" . $noteName['NoteName'] . "</div>";
        }

        echo "</div>";
        ?>
    </div>
    <div id="right-box">

    </div>
</div>

<!-- End Main Body Area -->
```

Ive just included my whole CSS File here so you can see all the classes

There is one for the [Animations](http://pastebin.com/ESzP2mzM) and One for [General Styles](http://pastebin.com/n5BkESe5)

Like i said its rather obscure and im not sure what extra info you require,

Please just ask and i can provide you with it.

So i ask, why is this only happening in Firefox?

Comment: Tables have always been ugly unless you're actually displaying tabular data. What if you remove that style?

Comment: Hi Sunny, the only table i used is the one for the header in which it is only three cells essentially, so which style am i removing? EDIT: I think i know which bit you are on about... the display: table; ?? if so i tried removing that and still happening :(

Comment: Start by fixing the HTML errors. https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.discovertheplanet.net%2F

Comment: Just remove display: table and display: table-cell from the containers. It should work on all browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the .main-container-notes height is causing this
try removing it

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this code:

```
#left-box {
vertical-align: top;
}
```

In my firefox it resolved your issue =) And this solution allows you to keep the height of .main-container-notes 1000px or whatever you want